Add server interface to VLAN
I have a Proxmox server and an Opnsense running on it. Several VLANs are running on the Opnsense with my LAN as the parent.
Currently a switch and my WLAN AP, which are connected via the LAN port, take care of adding VLAN tags to my devices.
However, I would now like to connect a device directly to a network port of my Proxmox server. The problem is that I don't know how to give this device a VLAN tag. There must be some way either via Proxmox or via Opnsense, but I haven't found it yet.
Here is the network configuration I have in mind.
It does not work, but if I leave out the .21 in the vmbr1 configuration it works so far that I end up in my LAN, but not in the right vlan.
# my pc
auto enp4s0f0
iface enp4s0f0 inet manual


# the vlan my pc is supposed to be in
auto enp4s0f0.21
iface enp4s0f0.21 inet manual
        vlan-raw-device enp4s0f0


# my LAN
auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address 10.2.100.1/16
        bridge-ports bond0 enp4s0f0.21
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        bridge-vlan-aware yes
        bridge-vids 2-4094

Thanks for your help :))

In principle, Proxmox is Debian, so Debian's networking manual is your essential reading. For us to be able to help, show us /etc/network/interfaces, and /etc/network/interfaces.d/* if any. And explain which NICs you see in the interfaces do what, and what server interface is supposed to be connected to the device and what tag it's expected to use.

@NikitaKipriyanov I have added my config to the question

When you say "it does not work", what exactly does happen? Do you end up with an interface enp4s0f0.21? Is attached to the vmbr bridge?

You are adding port bond0 to your vmbr bridge, but you don't appear to be configuring that in your interfaces file.

I expect bond0 to be defined in an interfaces file, or some file included from it, how else could it work? Anything than this, I don't see any apparent problems. Can you show ip link output after this config gets executed?
